# Java Spring Scheduling Service doesn't get newewst data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm an absolute spring boot beginner so I hope somebody can help me out.

I want to run a service which get's the newest User entries and does something with the user data for each user every day at a specific time. For that I guess I need to run a scheduler.

Therefor I have a class doSomethingDaily

```
@Service
public class doSomethingDaily {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepo; // extends CrudRepository
    

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void doSomething() {


         System.out.println("Is it time to do something?");
         
         // just for testing if user1 actually got found
         for( Account user : accountRepo.findAll() ) {
                System.out.println("Found user: " + user.getName());
             }





         //check if it's time for doing something

           // ... 
             for( Account user : accountRepo.findAll() ) {
                System.out.println("Found user: " + user.getName());
                // control/change some data from user
             }
          // ...
   
    }
    
}
```

Now I want to test the doSomethingDaily actually does its work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class doSomethingDailyTest {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepo;

    @Before 
    public void init() throws RepoAccessException {

        Account user1 = new Account();
        // use setter methods to fill user1 with data...
        // ...
        accountRepo.save( user1 );
    }
    
    
   
    @Test
    public void testDaily() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    }
}
```

Now I get to see the message "Is it time to do something?" a couple of times but no User Found message is displayed... can somebody explain me why?

Thanky you for reading

Comment: Try to debug your test to check if your user has been saved in init() and during your run of testDaily().

Comment: You should also improve your test instead of using Thread.sleep you can use something like await().atMost(Duration.seconds(10)).untilAsserted(() -> verify(doSomethingDaily, atLeast(1)).scheduled());

Comment: If I use the for loop before the Thread.sleep method I get to see my user1 name, so it should have been saved properly I think

Comment: Why don't you make sure?